# cant get data from api that uses brackets

Tags: javascript

How do I get example from JavaScript fetch when I get the response it comes like
so how can I get example.

```
[
  {
    example: 'true',  
  }
]
```

My code

```
    .then(res => res.json())
  .then(json => {
      console.log(json.example)
})
```

Comment: Square brackets in JavaScript represent an array (or list if you're used to Python syntax). Since there is only one element, you can use the 0 subscript to reference it. All together now: `json[0].example` should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

This is an array, so it should be accessible as `json[0].example`